# ListView not updating after FragmentTransaction & Network Requests

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, caching

I have a problem and I am not sure if it is related to (1) Android 7.0 (**Update**:  This is probably not related), (2) `Fragment` changes in the 25.x support libraries, or (3) Retrofit 1.9.

On any `Fragment` with a `ListView`, I make a network call (through the Retrofit library), and it returns data and populates the list.  Most of the time you will see a `ProgressDialog` for 1-2 seconds.

If I go back to the same `Fragment` later, the `ProgressDialog` displays for a fraction of a second (if it is in fact displaying at all).  Any changes made on my MySQL database are not reflected.  The list appears to be cached.  Force closing the app will not force an update.  Only if I clear the cache in the app settings will it reload.

I am not sure if this is another bug in the recent string of bugs in the recent libraries from Google in relation to `Fragment`s.  Or if Android 7.0 has a new way to implement `ListView`s.  OR Retrofit 1.9 (less likely I believe).

The only other detail I can give is this: `notifyDataSetChanged()` works fine after a list item is updated.  But the next time there is a `FragmentTransaction` and it is reloaded, it goes back to the old data (even though on the server the updates have been applied).

It has done this so far in 25.0.1 and 25.1.1 support versions for me.

Has anyone experienced this?

**UPDATE**:  I confirmed the issue on Android 4.2, so it seems to not be related to Android 7.0

Comment: Hi, I noticed something strange in Samsung Galaxy s7 Edge. It was related to cache. In my login screen user entered incorrect credentials, server would respond with error string, after that even if the user typed correct credentials (which were working from every other phone) it showed the same incorrect creds error message. When the cache was cleared, it worked fine. I still couldn't find the root cause, because I don't have that phone to test :) But I was not using any Fragments

Comment: @SharpEdge This sounds similar to me.  So maybe it is not `ListView` related?  Also, I confirmed it happens on Android 4.2 as well, so it is not Nougat related.  I am using a OnePlus 3, for what it's worth.

Comment: Its definitely not related to `ListView`. Do some quick checks, first when you go back to the fragment, is it created again or its the same one from memory ? Have you logged the data when you're fetching it from the server before adding it into the `ListView` ?

Comment: @SharpEdge I just logged the server side.  The first time around, I get a result from my SQL query.  The second time around (when we suspect it is being cached) I get nothing.  On the Android end:  When I log the Retrofit `success` function, it returns the same exact `List<MyObject>`, even if I add something to the database inbetween (which is being verified on the server).  This is starting to sound like a Retrofit issue.  Maybe i should roll back a version.

Comment: Android is so Random, always log your incoming/outgoing server data to make sure its correct :) It will make your life a little easier.